# "delete from table" doesn't delete table?

Tags: c++, sql, sqlite

I create "database.db" and everything goes ok but why wouldn't it delete the table at the end? Everytime i run it, i get "table already exist" error message on creating the table.

```
int main()
{
 sqlite3 *db; //Database Handle
 char *zErr;
 int rc;
 char *sql;

 rc = sqlite3_open("database.db", &db);

 if(rc)
 {
  cout << "Can't open database: " << sqlite3_errmsg(db) << endl;;
  sqlite3_close(db);
  exit(1);
 }

 sql = "create table test(PID int primary key, Name text)"; //sql query

 rc = sqlite3_exec(db, sql, NULL, NULL, &zErr); //execute sql statement

 if(rc != SQLITE_OK)
 {
  if (zErr != NULL)
  {
   cout << "SQL error: " << zErr << endl;
   sqlite3_free(zErr);
  }
 }
 else
 {
  sql = "insert into test values (1,'John')";
  rc = sqlite3_exec(db, sql, NULL, NULL, &zErr);

  sql = "insert into test values (2,'Smith')";
  rc = sqlite3_exec(db, sql, NULL, NULL, &zErr);
 }



    //delete the table on exit.

 rc = sqlite3_exec(db, "delete from test", NULL, NULL, &zErr);

 sqlite3_close(db);
 return 0;
}
```

Also, can the primary keys be auto-generated following the last greater key existing in database?

Comment: you mean auto_increment? yes sqlite supports auto_increment, you might want to take a look at Sqlite Manager plugin for firefox if you want to sit down and design the tables https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/5817/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use [`drop table`](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_droptable.html). [`delete`](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_delete.html) deletes rows in the table.

```
rc = sqlite3_exec(db, "drop table test", NULL, NULL, &zErr);
```

SQLite will auto-increment an integer field declared as the primary key. See [here](http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q1).

Answer (score 2):

You use a `DELETE` command to delete rows of a table.

You use a `DROP` command to drop a whole table or other DB item.

To create the table you can also use `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS` if you aren't sure if it exists.

To get your auto generated row ids use: `id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` in your `CREATE TABLE` command.

Answer (score 2):

1. Use [DROP TABLE](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_droptable.html).
2. From SQLite docs:

> The usual algorithm is to give the newly created row a ROWID that is one larger than the largest ROWID in the table prior to the insert.

Answer (score 0):

The DML "`delete from test`" does delete all the rows from the table test. If you wish to drop the table, try "`delete table test`" or "`drop table`" instead.